# Execute Yahoo YQL in hybridauth

Tags: php, yahoo-api, hybridauth

Im using [hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) to get Yahoo contacts. Hybridauth uses OAuth rest API to do the calls.

The Problem is that with rest API i dont get all contacts. If i use YQL in http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ i do get all contacts.

I have to types of contacts in Yahoo. A test contact i entered manually and contacts from Facebook that i imported using yahoo tool.

With YQL i get them all . With hybridauth rest api i only get one contact (the test one). So my question is if it's possible to execute YQL with hybridauth .

So far i tried in `hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Yahoo.php` :

```
$response = $this->api->get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20social.contacts(0)%20where%20guid%3Dme%3B', $parameters);
```

But is not working :(

Thanks!

Comment: I have a question. I am not quite sure why are you using YQL to get yahoo contacts. Why don't you use Yahoo Contact API to get all of your contacts.

Comment: I dont use YQL, i use hybridauth. Im pointing out that with YQL i get all contacts. With rest API used in hybridauth i dont

Comment: Got it. Are you able to get authenticated to access Yahoo API ? Did you do that check ?

Comment: Yes everything is working fine. I just tested the same account on cloudsponge and they also retrieve just the test contact. So it seems that yahoo only give all contacts using YQL